# Android RecyclerView Adapter notifyItemRemoved cause last element in the list to blink when animate

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am having an issue when calling `notifyItemRemoved(position)` on an adapter. Whenever the position I provided is not the last element, and when the removing animation happen, the last element will always "blink/flash" first before moving up as shown in the screenshot (link) below.

Here is a little snippet of my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...

        RecylerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter());
    }
```

**ItemAdapter.java**

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // mItems has a list of hard-coded elements
                mItems.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.myapp.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_click"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Has anyone gone through this and how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

[.gif of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTVrJ.gif)

Comment: Can you post the layout file or `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @azizbekian sorry I was busy. Yes, the xml have been added. I didn't add activity_main.xml because it's the default xml when creating a new project in Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the height of your Recycler view to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

In case, if you do not want any animation, you can add this line

```
((DefaultItemAnimator) recyclerViewObject.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your offer, but I want to have animation. :)

Comment: The solution i gave is will only remove animation on item addition and removal. default animation for adding and removing items in recyclerview is fadein-fadeout that is why you are seeing that blink. You can know more about it here.
http://frogermcs.github.io/recyclerview-animations-androiddevsummit-write-up/

Comment: I tried it but I am still getting the same result... Great reference link by the way

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code.

```
recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);
```

Comment: Hi @Faa I tried that but it didn't work. The problem is still there :(